# How to change #weight of fields added to user register page by form_alter()?

Tags: 7, forms

I have created some fields on my user registration page named like - 
First Name (machine name - field_first_name),
Last name (machine name - field_last_name) etc..

I want to change their `#weight` according to me to appear at the place where I like them to be from the form_alter function at my custom module..

For the default name & email I used -

```
$form['account']['name']['#weight'] = 7;
$form['account']['field_first_name']['#weight'] = 8;
```

& it worked..

But If I am using for added fields in this way like -

```
$form['account']['field_first_name']['#weight'] = 6;
```

It's not working...

Can I get any help in this ?

Comment: it depends on where you are keeping the fields. if it is with in a fields set then the weight will only be effected with in the fields set and not out side of it.

Comment: These are not inside the fieldset

Comment: account as a whole is in a group which contains the name password etc. the one we add might be out side of that...

Comment: @MohammedShameem - You were right. It's just independent and I could set the #weight by $form['field_first_name']['#weight'] = 6; , please give answer...I will accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account as a whole is in a group which contains the name password etc. The one we add might be out side of that. That is why it is not effecting the weight.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can copy the field in another "container field" and change the weight , something like this:

```
   $form['profile_one']['account'] = $form['account'];
   $form['profile_one']['account']['#weight'] = 200;

   // Hide login form from this render.
   $form['account']['#type'] = 'hidden';
```